# Django urlsafe base64 decoding with decryption

Tags: python, django, encryption, encoding, base64

I'm writing my own captcha system for user registration. So I need to create a suitable URL for receiving generated captcha pictures. Generation looks like this:

```
_cipher = cipher.new(settings.CAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY, cipher.MODE_ECB)
_encrypt_block = lambda block: _cipher.encrypt(block + ' ' * (_cipher.block_size - len(block) % _cipher.block_size)) 
#...
a = (self.rightnum, self.animal_type[1])
serialized = pickle.dumps(a)
encrypted = _encrypt_block(serialized)
safe_url = urlsafe_b64encode(encrypted)
```

But then I'm trying to receive this key via GET request in the view function, it fails on urlsafe_b64decode() with "character mapping must return integer, None or unicode" error:

```
def captcha(request):
  try:
    key = request.REQUEST['key']
    decoded = urlsafe_b64decode(key)
    decrypted = _decrypt_block(decoded)
    deserialized = pickle.loads(decrypted)
    return HttpResponse(deserialized)
  except KeyError: 
    return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

I found that on the output of urlsafe_b64encode there is an str, but GET request returns a unicode object (nevertheless it's a right string). Str() didn't help (it returns decode error deep inside django), and if I use key.**repr** it works, but decryptor doesn't work with an error "Input strings must be a multiple of 16 in length".
Inside a test file all this construction works perfectly, I can't understand, what's wrong?

Comment: Is the encryption necessary? Couldn't the generation of the captcha store the correct answer in session data server-side? Or are you trying to avoid that?

Comment: Just didn't think about it yet. But this problem is interesting and I want to understand why it happends.

Comment: `key = str(request.REQUEST['key'])` doesn't work?

Comment: It returns an error:
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/http/__init__.py", line 365, in _get_content
    return smart_str(''.join(self._container), self._charset)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The problem is that b64decode quite explicitly can only take bytes (a string), not unicode.

```
>>> import base64
>>> test = "Hi, I'm a string"
>>> enc = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(test)
>>> enc
'SGksIEknbSBhIHN0cmluZw=='
>>> uenc = unicode(enc)
>>> base64.urlsafe_b64decode(enc)
"Hi, I'm a string"
>>> base64.urlsafe_b64decode(uenc)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
TypeError: character mapping must return integer, None or unicode
```

Since you know that your data only contains ASCII data (that's what base64encode will return), it should be safe to encode your unicode code points as ASCII or UTF-8 bytes, those bytes will be equivalent to the ASCII you expected.

```
>>> base64.urlsafe_b64decode(uenc.encode("ascii"))
"Hi, I'm a string"
```

Comment: This helps for a related problem I have in a python webserver.

Comment: "you know that your data only contains ASCII data" -- and that is why I would write `.encode("ascii")`.

Comment: Yes, "ascii" would be better. Updated.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem!

```
deserialized = pickle.loads(captcha_decrypt(urlsafe_b64decode(key.encode('ascii'))))
return HttpResponse(str(deserialized))
```

But still I don't understand, why it didn't work first time.